# ArrayList weird issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, arraylist

I have set up an `Array` called `questions`, and I am pushing the results of an API into the `Array`, and this works with no problems.

If I hardcode the array I would set it up like this.

```
var questions = [
  {
    "The Eiffel Tower is located where in Paris?": [
      "Champ de Mars",
      "Bois de Boulogne",
      "Jardin des Plantes",
      "Parc de Belleville"
    ]
  }
]
```

But when I use a `questions.push` method I end up with this:

```
var questions = [ '
{
"Which of the following was not one of &#039;The Magnificent Seven&#039;?": [
"Clint Eastwood",
"Steve McQueen",
"Charles Bronson",
"Robert Vaughn"
]
}']
```

Why is it adding a weird `'` into my results?

Here is how I add the info into my Array:

```
var qdata = "{ \"" + question + "\":[ \"" + answer1 + "\", \"" + answer2 + "\", \"" + answer3 + "\", \"" + answer4 + "\"" + "]}";

questions.push(qdata);
```

I can't see why it is adding the `'` into my array.

Comment: The weird issue is due to weird usage. Why are you constructing the array that way? Why not plain old `var arr = [] // etc code be here`?

Comment: Well why are you building a string if you want an object?

Comment: Never used an array before, it was a new project and knew i was making a mistake which is why i asked for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are declaring your variable `qdata` you're setting it as a `String` not as an `Object`: `"{x: 123}"` vs `{x: 123}`, the first is a `String` which would make the object {x: 123} (the second example) if you were to copy paste it as it is (without the `"` of course).

So basically you simply need to change `qdata` into this:

```
var qdata = {}
qdata[question] = [answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4]
questions.push(qdata)
```

And if by any chance you're using ES6 it's even shorter:

```
questions.push({[question]: [answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4]})
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed and my skills is now working, thank you so much, i ahve marked your answer as correct

Comment: @DavidVicente Sorry if you felt that I copied your answer, but I did NOT copy yours. The answer is simple enough to be given similarly by any junior JavaScript developer. My answer came after yours because I took time to write it with more details and a better formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a string object in qdata and adding to the array, and that's what JavaScript is doing. The ' is because it is a string.

If you want to add objects, try something like this:

```
var objectQuestion = {};
objectQuestion[question] = [answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4];
questions.push(objectQuestion);
```

Comment: Thanks you for this, i will try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Well in your example qdata is just a String. You did not parse it to JSON.

Try using:

```
JSON.parse(qdata)
```

before pushing it to the array

more info: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Well this works, but it would be better if they did not build a string to start with.

Comment: Why making him use of `JSON.parse` if he already has the parsed data?

Comment: By all regards my solution may not be the best, but there is no parsed data yet when it is a string. He may recieve the data as a string who knows. However I do believe @JayDJohno is now able to figure out that he should not be pushing a string

Comment: Wow that makes so much sense haha, the data was already JSON and was parsed into a string i just needed to add it as an object.